# Quartz.net service, Scheduler has been disconnected or does not exist at server

Tags: asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using Quartz.net 2.2 installed as service. The jobs are stored in ms sql express, using AdoJobStore. The jobs are managed from an asp.net 4 website. 
Everything works fine, as expected: the service is running, the jobs are stored and triggered correctly.
The problem that I'm facing is that, every day after 7am (this is when the application pool recycles) and I visit the site, it gives this error:

> Object '/QuartzScheduler' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.
>
> [RemotingException: Object '/QuartzScheduler' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.]
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9443827
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +345
>   Quartz.Simpl.IRemotableQuartzScheduler.get_SchedulerName() +0
>   Quartz.Impl.RemoteScheduler.b__6(IRemotableQuartzScheduler x) +8
>   Quartz.Impl.RemoteScheduler.CallInGuard(Func`2 func) +61
>
> [SchedulerException: Error communicating with remote scheduler.]
>   Quartz.Impl.RemoteScheduler.CallInGuard(Func`2 func) +100
>   Quartz.Impl.RemoteScheduler.get_SchedulerName() +92
>   Quartz.Impl.SchedulerRepository.Bind(IScheduler sched) +65
>   Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Instantiate() +1815
>   Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler() +102
>   ASP.global_asax.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) +241
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Error communicating with remote scheduler.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9189101
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +194
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +253
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Error communicating with remote scheduler.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9104200
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +256

**After this, if I go to the server, and I stop/start Quartz.net service, then the site starts correctly.**

Same thing occurs every time I upload via FTP the web.config modified, or another file modified which causes the website to restart. Here I obtain the same error, which I can circumvent stopping and restarting Quartz.net service.

Here is the **global.asax** of the website:

```
public static ISchedulerFactory SchedulerFactory;
public static IScheduler Scheduler;

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameValueCollection p = new NameValueCollection();
    p["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "MyScheduler";
    p["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
    p["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "0";
    p["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = "tcp://localhost:555/QuartzScheduler";

    SchedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(p);
    Scheduler = SchedulerFactory.GetScheduler(); // <-- The exception seems to occur here

    if (!Scheduler.IsStarted)
        Scheduler.Start();
}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Scheduler.Shutdown(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there have been no answers regarding this matter, I'm posting what I did:
Removing `Scheduler.Shutdown(true);` from `void Application_End` solves the issue that occured after application recycle.
If someone else has a better answer and explanation I'll mark it as answer.

Comment: I made the same mistake here

Answer (score 0):

I have the approximately the same setup as you do :

- Service: Quartz host
- MVC web app: Quartz client

However, I have never encountered this error. Below are the key parts of my code, I hope it helps :

**Client parameters**

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = config.QuartzInstanceName;
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = "tcp://127.0.0.1:" + config.QuartzPort + "/" + config.QuartzInstanceName;
```

**Host parameters**

```
NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = config.QuartzInstanceName;
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "AUTO";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.port"] = config.QuartzPort;
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName"] = config.QuartzInstanceName;
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType"] = "tcp";
properties["quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelName"] = "httpQuartz";
properties["jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz";
```

**Client initialization**

```
// Note, this runs in an async loop, which keeps on trying to connect until it succeeds
// This is actually kinda ugly, needs to be refactored, but it works

while (mScheduler == null)
{
  try
  {
    StdSchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(schedulerFactoryProps);
    mScheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler()
    // Note that I do not use .Start() here
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }

  if (mScheduler == null)
    Thread.Sleep(SCHEDULER_RETRY_DELAY);
}
```

**Host initialization**

```
StdSchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(schedulerFactoryProps);
mScheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
mScheduler.Start();
```

Comment: I see your example and it differs from mine in some aspects. I solved it removing the Scheduler.Shutdown(true); and I have it running. I dont know why, but that solved the problem after application recycle.